# Trying to Merge two DataFrames by one column in R but having some trouble

Tags: r, merge

So I have two dataframes (1 and 2) and dataframe 1 has 261 rows and 36 columns and one of them is named "Player" column. Dataframe 2 has 249 rows and 6 columns and has the "Player" column as well. I want to figure out a way to merge dataframe 2 and add its 5 columns to dataframe 1 by matching its "Player" column with dataframe 1.

The closest I've gotten to achieve this is with this code:

```
dataframe1 <- merge(x = dataframe1, y = dataframe2, by = "Player", all.x =  TRUE)
```

With this code the new df has 261 rows and 40 columns which is what I want, but when I go to check the newly added columns, all the values for the columns brought over from dataframe 2 have NA values.

Is it due to dataframe 1 having twelve more columns than dataframe 2?

This is the output after running dput(head(BSN_stats1)) on dataframe 1:

```
structure(list(`#` = c(0, 2, 7, 9, 10, 14), Team = c("Capitanes", 
"Capitanes", "Capitanes", "Capitanes", "Capitanes", "Capitanes"
), Player = c("Thomas Robinson", "Aaron Harrison", "Marlon Hargis", 
"Perry Jones lll", "Víctor Liz", "Jorge Luis Torres"), GP = c(9, 
14, 13, 1, 31, 11), Minutes = c(160, 377, 47, 22, 871, 108), 
    MPG = c(17.8, 26.9, 3.6, 22, 28.1, 9.8), FG = c(37, 57, 5, 
    7, 127, 16), FGA = c(62, 143, 13, 11, 301, 22), `FG%` = c(0.597, 
    0.399, 0.385, 0.636, 0.422, 0.727), `TS%` = c(0.602, 0.536, 
    0.44, 0.918, 0.539, 0.71), `2P` = c(37, 25, 4, 1, 92, 16), 
    `2PA` = c(62, 55, 5, 3, 203, 22), `2P%` = c(0.597, 0.455, 
    0.8, 0.333, 0.453, 0.727), `3P` = c(0, 32, 1, 6, 35, 0), 
    `3PA` = c(0, 88, 8, 8, 98, 0), `3P%` = c(0, 0.364, 0.125, 
    0.75, 0.357, 0), FT = c(17, 21, 2, 1, 94, 8), FTA = c(31, 
    29, 4, 1, 123, 14), `FT%` = c(0.548, 0.724, 0.5, 1, 0.764, 
    0.571), DRB = c(25, 45, 9, 7, 117, 17), DRBPG = c(2.8, 3.2, 
    0.7, 7, 3.8, 1.5), ORB = c(24, 9, 2, 0, 52, 15), ORBPG = c(2.7, 
    0.6, 0.2, 0, 1.7, 1.4), TRB = c(49, 54, 11, 7, 169, 32), 
    RPG = c(5.4, 3.9, 0.8, 7, 5.5, 2.9), Assists = c(11, 24, 
    0, 1, 74, 5), APG = c(1.2, 1.7, 0, 1, 2.4, 0.5), Steals = c(1, 
    19, 0, 0, 41, 7), SPG = c(0.1, 1.4, 0, 0, 1.3, 0.6), Blocks = c(2, 
    4, 1, 1, 4, 3), BPG = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.1, 1, 0.1, 0.3), TO = c(14, 
    21, 2, 1, 66, 8), TOPG = c(1.6, 1.5, 0.2, 1, 2.1, 0.7), Points = c(91, 
    167, 13, 21, 383, 40), PPG = c(10.1, 11.9, 1, 21, 12.4, 3.6
    ), `USG%` = c(24.9, 20.8, 15.8, 25.1, 21.5, 14.9)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

And this is the output after running dput(head(BSN_info1)) on dataframe 2:

```
structure(list(Player = c("Raymond Cintrón Cortés", "Thomas Robinson ", 
"Aaron Harrison ", "Stephen Zimmerman ", "Víctor Liz ", "Chinemelu Elonu "
), Age = c(33, 32, 29, 27, 36, 36), Position = c("Escolta", "Delantero/Centro", 
"Escolta", "Centro", "Escolta", "Centro"), Height = c("6'0", 
"6'10", "198", "213", "6'2", "6'10"), Weight = c(200L, 237L, 
90L, 109L, 180L, 235L), Team = c("Capitanes", "Capitanes", "Capitanes", 
"Capitanes", "Capitanes", "Capitanes")), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Would appreciate any help on this.

Comment: `dput(dataframe1)` and `dput(dataframe2)` (or alternatively, `dput(head(dataframe1))` and `dput(head(dataframe2))`. Run these, edit your question, and copy paste the outputs of them into your question. Please and thank you!

Comment: Check your `Player` columns. An `NA` indicates that there wasn't a match.

Comment: Check also if there are any actual matches between `Player` values in both data frames: `intersect(dataframe1$Player, dataframe2$Player) |> unique() |> length()`. If there are no matches, the values of the columns from `dataframe2` will be filled with `NA`. I would also check if the class of the columns is the same, just in case.

Comment: When attempting to merge by a character column, pay particular attention to (trailing) whitespace.

Comment: @stepback3 you might need to include the rest of your data, maybe elsewhere, or otherwise cull the number of columns until you get under the character limit. The head of both dfs don't have a common Player, so it's not going to match anything